# What is this error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ArticlesController#show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

error :

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: articles.slug: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."slug" = '33' ORDER BY "articles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

code :

```
def show
  @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @category = Category.find(@article.category_id)
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

Comment: i am trying to use gem called friendly and i am using the friendly keyword in show action but i am getting the error like this

Comment: can someone solve my error?

Comment: You might have forgotten including the generated migrations. Run `rails generate friendly_id` and then `rails db:migrate`. Refer to the docs [here](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

Comment: yes, i have done it but i am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

`@article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])`

This will look for a `slug` column in the database’s `articles` table so you’ll need to create it and you’ll create a migration to do so.

```
$ rails g migration add_slug_to_articles slug:string
```

It’s a good idea to add an `index` for this attribute as it will be used for finding records.

```
class AddSlugToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :slug, :string
    add_index :articles, :slug
  end
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate` now good to go

```
@article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: yes i did it even though it is displaying the id of the article in url insted of name of the article .....what to do?

Comment: @Shivakumara m can you tell me how are you coming to `show` action, i mean if you are using `link_to` what is that `url` which redirect it show action. please share `link_to .... `

Comment: you should use like this  example `<%= link_to 'Article', article_path(id: article.slug)%>` please cross check it if you are passing `article.slug` for `id` attribute